# What happens with a premature 'return' in an ISR?

Tags: embedded, avr, isr

I'm using AVR-GCC 4.9.2, and I would like to know what happens if I do a premature return in an ISR on an AVR?

```
ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
    ...
    if(idx == BUFSIZE)
        return;
    ...
 }
```

Will the `return` be translated to a `reti` instruction? Or do I need to include a `reti()` myself?

I'm looking for a detailed explanation of what goes on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just as
`ISR(USART_RXC_vect)`
is not literally just
`USART_INTERUPT_VECTOR:`
in Assembler,

`return;`
is not literally just
`ret`
or
`reti`
in Assembler.

Both instructions in C/C++ will be translated into multiple Assembler statements and in both cases it will depend on context. The context for  an `ISR(){}` is quite one-track in this case, but it will most likely also include a few pushes and storing the SREG. But the number of pushes to the stack will depend on what happens in the function.

So will any `return;` be interpreted in context. At the end of a normal subroutine that actually gets built into a subroutine (many subroutines of limited use get "in-lined" by a compiler for code efficiency reasons) it will become a `ret` instruction (after handling any needed POPs and other low-level clean-up). At the end of an interrupt it will actually mean "pop everything you pushed before (and also restore the SREG) and then `reti`".

When you return a type that will get compiled into transferring that value through the platform's system, before including the `ret` instruction. So `return;` is a very context sensitive statement that you can assume will be interpreted correctly, unless you do very weird things. But those weird things will be things a good compiler (like AVR-GCC) will at the least warn for.